# Difference between searching by URL and post body

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm trying to construct a search query based on object's property value, that is inside a nested array.

**It works fine**:

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/products/product/_search?q=items.sku:ABC123'
```

**This doesn't work**. Why, what am I missing?:

```
{
  "_source" : "items",
  "query": {
    "term" : {
      "items.sku" : "ABC123"
    }
  }
}
```

The item I want to retrieve looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Example product"
  "brand" : {
    "id" : 123,
    "name" : "Nike"
  },
  "items" : [
    {
      id: 234,
      sku: "ABC123"
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      sku: "XYZ963"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what analyser do you have on items.sku?  can you post your mapping?  its likely that the data "ABC123" is being broken up into multiple indexed terms when it's stored. When you do a term search you're telling ES to looking for that exact string - try switching to query_string or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query doesn't work because it's not using the same operator than the `q` operator.

The `q` operator is a "shortcut" to the use of a `query_string` query. The equivalent query to what you did would in fact be the following :

```
{
  "_source": "items",
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "items.sku:ABC123"
    }
  }
}
```

which outputs the document as expected :

```
"hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.19178301,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "product",
            "_id": "AU_VTrjXeQSEeO15aKQi",
            "_score": 0.19178301,
            "_source": {
               "items": [
                  {
                     "id": 234,
                     "sku": "ABC123"
                  },
                  {
                     "id": 456,
                     "sku": "XYZ963"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Difference is that the `term` query search for values that are **not analyzed** (which in your example, would be ABC123) whereas `query_string` choose to analyze or not the value according to the mapping of the field being queried.

I think that in your case, the mapping of your field `items.sku` is simply `string`, which means that by default, your field is **analyzed** with `standard` analyzer : your value has been indexed as `abc123` because it has been lowercased (see [standard analyzer documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html?q=stand)).

I advise you to read the analysis section of the ElasticSearch Definitive Guide (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-analysis.html?q=analysis#mapping-analysis)) to have a better understanding of this.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, the difference is clear now. Apart from this, can you please explain or give a hint regarding how do I construct a proper POST body without using the `query_string`? I want to learn how to query nested arrays like in my example without falling back to `query_string`.

Comment: Your update makes perfect sense, please ignore my comment above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :) The go-to query you should look at is the `match` query family which is more user-friendly with analysis (as `query_string`, it knows when to analyze a value or not). Beware of the multiple nested objects too! There are pitfalls which are well explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)
 )